# How can i make a primary key chose the table to link to between two tables (specifically where the primary key exists)?

Tags: java, sql, mysql, database, database-design

I have three tables of concern to my problem: students, staff, and issued_books. The issued_books table has book_id column (reference to the books table) and user_id column (reference to either students or staff table, depending on which of the two tables has the inserted user_id).

```
CREATE TABLE issued_books(
issue_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    book_id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    user_id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    -- other column
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books (book_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES students (user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES staff (user_id)
    );
```

This is what i have. If the user_id is found in students table, i want to establish the foreign key with the table. Otherwise, the staff table. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like it is clumsy to start with a `book` and find the `student` or `staff` to whom it is issued.  Rethink the schema design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you want to enforce the issued book is either related to a student or to staff, not both, not none.

In this case both foreign keys should be nullable only one at a time. You do that by keeping both of them nullable, and adding a CHECK constraints the enforces that one and only one of them is null at any given time.

For example, you can do:

```sql
create table issued_books (
  issue_id int primary key,
  book_id varchar(15) not null,
  student_id varchar(15) null, -- nullable
  staff_id varchar(15) null, -- nullable
  -- other columns
  foreign key (book_id) references books (book_id),
  foreign key (student_id) references students (user_id),
  foreign key (staff_id) references staff (user_id),
  check (student_id is null and staff_id is not null or
         student_id is not null and staff_id is null)
);
```

Alternatively, you could resolve this issue adopting an inheritance design. Inheritance is not a *native* thing for relational databases, and the solutions are clunky at best. See [Table Inheritance Design Strategies](https://bitbucket.org/impalerthe/k2/src/7b37052251e3397852a0cc3570f6ef66732e7c4a/database/design/table-inheritance.md).